# Reading a specific line in a text file to a set "lineinfo=text on line 1 or 2" in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, text

im trying to make a batch file read a specific line from a text file, and set NewHDLocation="then here is the text from the line in the txt", and then do that 2 times so i later can do %NewHDLocation% and %WOTinstalldir% to tell commands that information

sample of my code:

```
for /F "skip=0 delims=" %%i in (Settings.txt) do if not defined NewHDLocation set "NewHDLocation=%%i"&goto next

:next
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%i in (Settings.txt) do if not defined WOTinstalldir set "WOTinstalldir=%%i"&goto next2

:next2
@echo %NewHDLocation%
@echo %WOTinstalldir%
pause
```

the last 2 @echo is just to test if it get the information from the txt but it just outputs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "skip=0 delims=" %i in (Settings.txt) do if not defined NewHDLocation set "NewHDLocation=%i"  & goto next
 delims=" was unexpected at this time.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "skip=1 delims=" %i in (Settings.txt) do if not defined WOTinstalldir set "WOTinstalldir=%i"  & goto next2

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if not defined WOTinstalldir set "WOTinstalldir=ECHO is on."  & goto next2
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

in the text file i need to read from i wrote (just for testing):

```
New_HDfiles_Drive
WOT_Install_Location
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular instance I would probably just stream the file into a code block.

```
@ECHO OFF
<settings.txt (
set /p "NewHDLocation="
set /p "WOTinstalldir="
)

echo %NewHDLocation%
echo %WOTinstalldir%
pause
```